# Create a docker image of a postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, docker

I am a beginner to Docker, and I would like to know how can I create a Docker image of my existing postgresql database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to pull the standard, preconfigured Postgres image (of the appropriate version) from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/). Set it up with a volume for storing the database. Use `pg_dump` to export your existing database, and `pg_restore` to the new one.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, do I need an image of my linux pc or of postgresql?

Comment: The Postgresql Docker image contains a stripped-down Linux system with a Postgres server. You don't need to make any image yourself, just use the official one. The page linked above has good instructions.